# Sorting ArrayList by string values as double

Tags: android, arraylist

I need to sort an ArrayList by a certain value.

In this case, the list object getUsers23 is a String, but I need to compare that value as double.

Example value or getUser23 = "67.455432434234"

At the moment, using Collections.sort() to sort the arrayList is sorting the arrayList by getUser23 as string value:

```
  Collections.sort(spotsList1, new Comparator<Spots>(){
            public int compare(Spots obj1, Spots obj2) {

                return obj1.getUsers23().compareToIgnoreCase(obj2.getUsers23()); 

            }
        });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you have 67.455432434234 stored against getUser23 in your object?

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, yes but as string value

Comment: If you have getter for that then you can do Double.valueOf("67.455432434234") or Double.parseDouble("67.455432434234") as @Farid mentioned to convert to double  and then compare

Comment: convert the string to double using 'Double.parseDouble(getUsers23())' then compare them

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela. just before the return or inside the return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to double and then compare.

Modify your code inside comparator as

```
try{
    return Double.valueOf(obj1.getUsers23()).compareTo(Double.valueOf(obj2.getUsers23()));
}catch (Exception e){
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: let me try it out